# AngularJs, filter "afoo" but not "foo"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I try to manage a filter in a ng-repeat

**Main.HTML**

```
<table>
       <tr ng-repeat="param in MyParam | filter: UnrequestValue">
          <td>{{param.Label}}</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

**Main.js**

```
MyParam: Array<parameter>;
param1: parameter;
param2: parameter;
param3: parameter;

$scope.UnrequestValue = "!foo";

$scope.param1 = "TooFoo";
$scope.param2 = "Foo";
$scope.param3 = "Too";

$scope.param1.Label = "this is TooFoo";
$scope.param2.Label = "this is Foo";
$scope.param2.Label = "this is Too";
```

I would like to print:

- this is TooFoo
- this is Too

But I have currently getting the result as :

- this is Too

Here my filter are not working properly as expected.
As i need to follow the spec, so I can't change the labels.
 .

Can anyone know to solve this problem  ?
It worked fine with ng-if.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you trying to do ??

Comment: I have one Array, used in two tab. Once must show every element, the other juste some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps ,you have to write a custom filter which returns the mismatch values

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('weDontLike', function(){

    return function(items, name){

        var arrayToReturn = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            if (items[i].name != name) {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});

function HelloCntl($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [
        {
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'},
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'},
    {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'},
    {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'}
    ];
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/bens/CBgcP/](http://fiddle)